# When Master scroll will work then both arrow will be in middle

Tags: html, reactjs, antd

How we can set 2 arrow left and right it will be in middle when scroll. I have table header fixed on top on vertical scroll in antd with full window with in Table Area and When Master scroll will work then both arrow will be in middle.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-hi94u

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is with the scroll and the arrows, but the arrows where throwing an error on Click.

```
<Pagination
  total={10}
  showTotal={(total, range) =>
    `Showing ${range[0]}-${range[1]} of ${total} items`
  }
  defaultPageSize={100}
  defaultCurrent={0}
  onPageChange={(current, pageSize) => this.onPageChange()}
  showSizeChanger={true}
  pageSizeOptions={["100", "150", "200"]}
  onShowSizeChange={(current, pageSize) =>
    this.onPageChange(current, pageSize)
  }
/>
```

This above it's working now when you click the arrows but there is not enough items to go to the following page. Notice the change of `onChange` to `onPageChange={(current, pageSize) => this.onPageChange()}`. Does this resolve your question?